# elasticsearch, spring-data and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to add elastic search to my project. I was using `hibernate` as `ORM` to access my data. I want to index some of my entities to the `elasticsearch` cluster.

To do that I had the idea to use my current existing hibernate entity class and add the `spring-data-elasticsearch` annotation in addition to the hibernate ones.

I am not totally confident in this choice and I wonder if there is some design error in it (possible conflicts between annotations?).

For instance, I have to put 2 Id annotation : `"@javax.persistence.Id`" for `hibernate` and "`@org.springframework.data.annotation.Id`" for elastic search.

Thank in advance for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully configure and test my idea of using the same class for db storage and elasticsearch indexing. I realized that the ES indexer include EVERY field of the class, not only the "elastic search annotated".

More of that, the spring-data-elasticsearch are not usefull. I think it is because the ES indexer use JPA annotation, and every field of my class already had its own for hibernate...

In conclusion, I am going to do a class for db storage, and another one (with less info) for my ES indexation.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to consider the native Hibernate integration with Elasticsearch:
 - http://in.relation.to/2016/05/24/ElasticsearchintegrationReachesBeta1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Both Spring Data JPA and SPring Data Elasticsearch in same time. Use this config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ElasticsearchCrudRepository.class))
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ElasticsearchCrudRepository.class))
public class DataConfiguration {
    ...
}
```